# Referencing parameters with names when using itertools.product

Tags: python

I want to use python to operate on all the combinations of about 8 parameters, evaluating each combination for its impact on the system.

I was thinking of ways that are nicer than 8 nested `for` loops and found out about `itertools.product`. This gives a much flatter structure but what's a good way of referring to the results from `product`? With the nested loops *each parameter in the combination has a handy name to refer to it*. With the itertools approach I have some code to set up names for the parameter in the sequence.

Example (with only 3 parameters and poor file handling):

**Nested loops version**

```
import csv
import itertools

csv_writer = csv.writer(open('data.csv', 'wb'))
csv_writer.writerow(("x", "y", "bpp", "raw_size_bytes", "file_size_bytes"))

# 8bpp and below needs 1 byte per pixel, 9 to 16 bpp needs 2 bytes
file_bytes_per_pixel = [1]*9 + [2]*8

# iterate over parameter combination in nested "for"
for x in [640, 1024, 2048]:
    for y in [320, 1024, 1024]:
        for bpp in [8,10, 16]:
            raw_size_bytes = (x * y * bpp) / 8
            file_size_bytes = x * y * file_bytes_per_pixel[bpp]
            csv_writer.writerow((x, y, bpp, raw_size_bytes, file_size_bytes))
```

**Continuing into itertools version**

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(open('data2.csv', 'wb'))
csv_writer.writerow(("x", "y", "bpp", "raw_size_bytes", "file_size_bytes"))
range_x = [640, 1024, 2048]
range_y = [320, 1024, 1024]
range_bpp = [8,10, 16]

for x, y, bpp in itertools.product(range_x, range_y, range_bpp):
    raw_size_bytes = (x * y * bpp) / 8
    file_size_bytes = x * y * file_bytes_per_pixel[bpp]
    csv_writer.writerow((x, y, bpp, raw_size_bytes, file_size_bytes))
```

In the itertools version I repeat the meaning of the different parameters four times

1. writing the csv file headings
2. setting up the ranges
3. passing the ranges to `product`
4. giving names to the results from `product`

**Indexes defined with names**

There's perhaps an improvement if I give numbers to the parameter names:

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(open('data3.csv', 'wb'))

x, y, bpp = range(3)
params = range(3)

params[x] = [640, 1024, 2048]
params[y] = [320, 1024, 1024]
params[bpp] = [8, 10, 16]

csv_writer.writerow(("x", "y", "bpp", "raw_size_bytes", "file_size_bytes"))

for p in itertools.product(*params):
    raw_size_bytes = (p[x] * p[y] * p[bpp]) / 8
    file_size_bytes = p[x] * p[y] * file_bytes_per_pixel[p[bpp]]
    csv_writer.writerow((p[x], p[y], p[bpp], raw_size_bytes, file_size_bytes))
```

I feel like I'm repeating myself only twice but I do have `p[]` each time I refer to a result from product.

If I had the parameters in an (ordered) dictionary then I could use `.keys()` to get the list of names and `.values()` to get the ranges for `product`. But then I don't know of a way of getting the results from `product` into variables with good names to do the calculations on.

In the course of asking the question I feel like I've got to a way of doing it that I'm reasonably happy with, but is there an even cleaner way of using product and being able to refer to the individual members of the sequence returned from it in a sensible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the process of asking the question I think I answered it, the cleanest way of doing it seems to be to use "product" with a dictionary.

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(open('data3.csv', 'wb'))

x, y, bpp = range(3)
params = range(3)

params[x] = [640, 1024, 2048]
params[y] = [320, 1024, 1024]
params[bpp] = [8, 10, 16]

csv_writer.writerow(("x", "y", "bpp", "raw_size_bytes", "file_size_bytes"))

for p in itertools.product(*params):
    raw_size_bytes = (p[x] * p[y] * p[bpp]) / 8
    file_size_bytes = p[x] * p[y] * file_bytes_per_pixel[p[bpp]]
    csv_writer.writerow((p[x], p[y], p[bpp], raw_size_bytes, file_size_bytes))
```

Answer (score 1):

This feels a little underwhelming [@sparklewhiskers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23402/sparklewhiskers) but you could take this approach to your last 4 lines to reduce the appearance of repetition :)

```
out = ((x, y, bpp, x * y * bpp / 8, x * y * file_bytes_per_pixel[bpp]) for
        x, y, bpp in itertools.product(range_x, range_y, range_bpp))
csv_writer.writerow(out)
```

I'm not familiar with writerow so you might need to output a list rather than a generator.